# Issue with installation of PhantomJS

Tags: npm, phantomjs

I get an issue when setting up PhantomJS on Ubuntu 14.04, I used NPM to install it but it doesn't work and the installation is stopped at "70%"...

Command : sudo npm install phantomjs --save

```
> phantomjs@1.9.17 install /var/www/gestiaweb/GestionDettes.3000/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Saving to /var/www/gestiaweb/GestionDettes.3000/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Receiving...
  [============================------------] 70% 0.0s
Received 12854K total.
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /var/www/gestiaweb/GestionDettes.3000/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /var/www/gestiaweb/GestionDettes.3000/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1435657830806/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 -> /var/www/gestiaweb/GestionDettes.3000/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /var/www/gestiaweb/GestionDettes.3000/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
phantomjs@1.9.17 node_modules/phantomjs
├── which@1.0.9
├── progress@1.1.8
├── kew@0.4.0
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── npmconf@2.1.1 (ini@1.3.4, uid-number@0.0.5, inherits@2.0.1, once@1.3.2, osenv@0.1.3, config-chain@1.1.9, nopt@3.0.3, semver@4.3.6, mkdirp@0.5.1)
└── request@2.42.0 (caseless@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.4.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, qs@1.2.2, node-uuid@1.4.3, mime-types@1.0.2, form-data@0.1.4, bl@0.9.4, http-signature@0.10.1, tough-cookie@2.0.0, hawk@1.1.1)
icecom@web-test:/var/www/gestiaweb/GestionDettes.3000$
```

Comment: Looks like it installed fine to me, the percentage could be incorrect if it is downloading in chunks.  Have you tried running it?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work when running it, `html-pdf` don't create any PDF. `html-pdf` install himself `phantomjs`...

Answer (score 3):

Put the executable into a directory that is in PATH (or put a symlink into PATH) or let NPM install it globally:

```
npm -g install phantomjs
```

Comment: or if it is installed only do a `ln` from bin of phantomjs